# manually implementing jackson serialization ignores annotations

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

When using jackson default writer, such as below :

```
 protected static String getAsJson(Class clazz, Object object) throws IOException {
    ObjectWriter ow = objectMapper.writerWithType(clazz);
    return ow.writeValueAsString(object);
```

Annotations such as below are ignored :

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateSerializer.class)
@Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDate")
private LocalDate date;
```

How can I manually implement the default jackson serialization that is used with springs `@Responsebody` (which works fine with the annotations) ?

Comment: Are you registering custom De/Serializer with the Mapper as mentioned here.. http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers

Comment: Forgot to ask: ignores how? What is not working?

Comment: @StaxMan the jsonserialize annatoation, the link above fixed it for me, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Jackson only recognizes annotations it knows about: and I am guessing that in your example, `@JsonSerialize` and `@JsonDeserialize` are Jackson annotations (from Jackson databind package), but `@Type` is something different (provided by Spring MVC, perhaps).
This means something else would be using that annotation (Spring).

It is possible to extend `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` to recognize other annotation types, so this may be something you can do. There is a method that deals with finding explicit type overrides which you could override.